# R reference column while using apply down rows

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

If I have some data that may be modelled so:

```
c1 <- c("A","B","C","A")
c2 <- c("a", "a", "b", "c")
c3 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
c4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1)
c5 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0)

df <- data.frame(c1 = c1, c2 = c2, c3 = c3, c4 = c4, c5 = c5)
```

I want to have an array `array.filled` that for columns 3:5 fills from `c1` if `0` and `c2` if `1`.

I was thinking of doing this with `apply` and `ifelse` but dont know how to refer to the columns with `apply(df, 2, function(x), ifelse(x == 0, ?, x))` (In this case I would do this twice).

Comment: Actually my data is a data.frame so I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About `ifelse()`**

The basic use of `ifelse` is as:

```
ifelse(c3 == 0, c1, c2)  ## ifelse(condition, if(TRUE), if(FALSE))
```

If `c3 == 0` it takes `c1`; otherwise it takes `c2`. You can also see `?ifelse` for more.

**Use `apply()`**

To apply this to `df[, 3:5]`, do:

```
foo <- function(x, opt0, opt1) ifelse(x == 0, opt0, opt1)
array.filled <- apply(df[, 3:5], 2, foo, opt0 = df[, 1], opt1 = df[, 2])

#     c3  c4  c5 
#[1,] "A" "A" "a"
#[2,] "a" "B" "B"
#[3,] "C" "C" "C"
#[4,] "A" "c" "A"
```

**Use `sapply()`**

An alternative/better way is to use `sapply`:

```
# still using the `foo` defined above
array.filled <- sapply(df[3:5], foo, opt0 = df$c1, opt1 = df$c2)

#     c3  c4  c5 
#[1,] "A" "A" "a"
#[2,] "a" "B" "B"
#[3,] "C" "C" "C"
#[4,] "A" "c" "A"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use this for a data frame where the columns are named?

Answer (score 2):

Use matrix indexing and avoid potentially costly looping:

```
sel <- cbind(seq(1,nrow(df)), unlist(df[3:5]+1, use.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE))
replace(df[3:5], TRUE, df[1:2][sel])

#  c3 c4 c5
#1  A  A  a
#2  a  B  B
#3  C  C  C
#4  A  c  A
```

This basically stores a row/column index in `sel`, which is used to subset the appropriate values from `df[1:2]`, which are then used to overwrite the values already existing in `df[3:5]`

It will be quicker, but of course, that may not be of any concern if you only have relatively small datasets. Both of the other answers run in reasonable times by my testing, until you get to very large data of the order of 10M records.

Answer (score 1):

While playing with the  accepted answer above following worked too for my real data:

```
my.array.filled <- apply(df[, 3:5], 2, function(x) ifelse(x == 0, df$c1, df$c2))
```

Its obviously the same but may be simpler to read.